# How do I use async_sinatra with hoptoad exception notifier?

Tags: exception, sinatra, hoptoad

It seems like async_sinatra swallows the exception before it can be passed to hoptoad.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Async_sinatra provides the handle_exception! hook, which you ought to be able to use to handle the exception. Declare a function in your main Sinatra class:

```
def handle_exception!(boom)
  # Log, print, send to Hoptoad/Airbrake etc.
end
```

Source code at:

https://github.com/raggi/async_sinatra/blob/master/lib/sinatra/async.rb#L129